# Second store not showing product images

Tags: product-images, media

On my second site everything seems to be working fine..except one thing, the product images! On the list and grid view from the category all images are being displayed, not a problem. However, when I'm on the product page, NOTHING!

catalog.xml
Inside catalog_product_view I have this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

Then on the view.phtml I have:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('media');
```

When I turn on html path hints, there is no hint to any media.phtml yet the file really exists. Furstrating how such a simple thing takes up so much time, hope I'm just overlooking something.

Worth to mention, on the main site, it's all working fine.

Comment: if it works on the first, what have you changed between them? Different template, module?